# iOS app crashes due to unknown error NO_CRASH_STACK + 0

Tags: ios, xcode

Users complained that the application began to crash at startup. Users use ios 9.3 or 10.3. Application crashes due to an unknown error. This error is not reported in Crashlytics. I see an error in Xcode - Window - Organizer - Crashes, but there are no details:

```
NO_CRASH_STACK + 0
```

Running the application on the iPhone 5 emulator with iOS 10.3.4 does not result in an error. I took a real iPhone 5 device with iOS 10.3.4. I launched my application from Xcode, the application does not crash. Installed the same application from the AppStore - the application crashes. I assume that the application does not crash if launched from Xcode, since the application does not have access to iTunes Connect under a real Apple ID in the debug mode. I added a sandbox account instead of a real account, I tested the purchase, the application does not crash when using the test environment and sandbox account.

If on iPhone 5 log in under a real Apple ID, cause a crash by launching the application, then in Xcode - Window - Devices and Simulators, I select iPhone 5, then View Device Logs. This window has the information below.

How can I determine exactly where an error occurs? Is it possible to test a connection to the iTunes Connect using real Apple ID on iPhone 5 iOS 10.3.4 on the XCode? I have iPhone XS max also and on this device I can connect to the iTunes Connect using real Apple ID in the XCode debug mode, but can't on iPhone 5.

```
Date / Time: 2020-05-13 11: 21: 41.2938 +0300
Launch Time: 2020-05-13 11: 21: 40.0000 +0300
OS Version: iPhone OS 10.3.4 (14G61)
Report Version: 104

Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00b485b0
Termination Signal: Bus error: 10
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xa
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread: 0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0 ??? 0x00b485b0 0 + 11830704
1   ??? 0x17e57c04 0 + 400915460
2 dyld 0x004d6da4 0x4b2000 + 150948
3 dyld 0x004be150 ImageLoaderMegaDylib :: incrementCoalIterator + 49488 (ImageLoader :: CoalIterator &) + 0

Thread 1:
0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x1a84e454 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x1a84e454 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x1a84e454 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name: com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x1a784900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x1a7846e0 mach_msg + 44
2 CoreFoundation 0x1af87be2 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 144
3 CoreFoundation 0x1af86064 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436
4 CoreFoundation 0x1aed91ae CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
5 CoreFoundation 0x1aed8fd0 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
6 Foundation 0x1b82daf4 - [NSRunLoop + 47860 (NSRunLoop) runMode: beforeDate:] + 258
7 Foundation 0x1b84a76c - [NSRunLoop + 165740 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 86
8 UIKit 0x20b62ad8 - [UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 128
9 Foundation 0x1b9118ea __NSThread__start__ + 1122
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x1a85093a _pthread_body + 216
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x1a85085c _pthread_start + 234
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x1a84e468 thread_start + 8

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000 r1: 0x00000004 r2: 0x00000003 r3: 0x0061c200
    r4: 0x00000005 r5: 0x00000000 r6: 0x00000001 r7: 0x0061c09c
    r8: 0x0061c060 r9: 0x00000000 r10: 0x004c972d r11: 0x004e34dc
    ip: 0x00b32f68 sp: 0x0061c044 lr: 0x00000000 pc: 0x00b485b0
  cpsr: 0x60000010

Binary Images:...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved with help from Apple Support

> there is a bug in the compiler that is producing bad armv7 code,
>   causing this crash. It is addressed in the Xcode 11.5 beta. To avoid
>   this bug, please compile with Xcode 11.3 instead of Xcode 11.4, and
>   disable bitcode so the App Store doesn’t recompile your app with the
>   compiler that has this issue. When Xcode 11.5 is released, please
>   re-enable bitcode.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was problems with dependencies.
We use CocoaPods and SPM.SnapKit added by SPM were crashes on Iphone 5, ios 9.

Try to check dependencies if you use SPM.

Comment: I do not use SPM

Answer (score 0):

Here are a lists of things you can do

1. Clean the build folder
2. Delete the detrieved data
3. Delete xcode followed by the developer folder in you library

If that does work, comment